# System Tray Icons on Xmonad - Xmobar Or any other minimal status bar

Tags: window-manager, notifications, xmonad

I am using slack desktop client on my Arch Linux. I am using Xmonad Window manager along with the [Xmobar](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/xmobar/) status bar.

On other Desktop environments, for example XFCE, the Slack Desktop client shows a small Icon (System tray icons) on the status bar, which is really helpful.

( Screenshots below are of Slack on XFCE )

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I like to use Xmonad with Xmobar (which looks like this -> )

[image]

Is there any way to get the slack icon on xmobar?

If not, is there any good, simple and minimal status bar which I could use on Xmonad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, with the help of nice people on #xmonad IRC channel, I got the solution

[image]

Here is how :

First I resized the xmobar to leave a small gap on Right side (editing xmobarrc)

```
position = Static { xpos = 0, ypos = 0, width = 1346, height = 20 },
```

Use the package `stalonetray`

```
sudo pacman -S stalonetray
```

Configure `stalonetray` with `~/.stalonetrayrc` file

```
decorations none
transparent false
dockapp_mode none
geometry 1x1-0+0
background "#000000"
kludges force_icons_size
grow_gravity NW
icon_gravity NW
icon_size 18
sticky true
#window_strut none
window_type dock
window_layer bottom
no_shrink false
skip_taskbar true
```

Finally, added it to `.xintrc`

You can even configure it to show multiple system tray icons

[image]

Thats it :)

Comment: `TopP 0 20` is a slightly more flexible way than `Static { ... }` to specify a gap on the right side.